# Template/class systemic literature review

Tags: templates, document-classes

I'm looking for a template (or a class) to write a systematic literature review in Public Health Sciences.

I can use the article class, or a specific class as oup-contemporary; but I'm wondering if such a template exists? I didn't find any specific template for a systematic literature review. If I can't find it, I can create one with the article class.

Comment: why can't you use `article` with the section names you show, what do you want that is different, your question is not at all clear.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can use article class, but, generally I prefer start working from a template to have better results without spending too much time in formatting it. I have some difficultes to insert a PRISMA flowchart for exemple.  I was wondering if there was already a template for a literature review? I use oup-contemporary class. It' awesome, but when I put the code of Tikz flowchart It covers all page. Perhaps it would be better if I opened a specific question?

Comment: It's ok for insert the flowchart, but my question is just "Is there a systematic litterature review template ?"